# How do I send a byte array to a function?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, byte

I have a problem with a function.
I want to send bytes to through a tcp socket.
However I have not figured out how to do that as I get warnings that my types don't machs
here's the code:
This is in the application viewcontroller:

```
-(IBAction) sendClicked:(id)sender{
    Byte sendBuffer[10];
    sendBuffer[0]=1;
    sendBuffer[1]=0;
    sendBuffer[2]=1;
    sendBuffer[3]=0;
    sendBuffer[4]=1;
    sendBuffer[5]=0;
    sendBuffer[6]=0;
    sendBuffer[7]=1;
    sendBuffer[8]=0;
    sendBuffer[9]=1;

if(tcp) [tcp sendData: *sendBuffer]

}
```

and this is in the tcp.m file:

```
-(void) sendData: (Byte*) sendBytes {
    NSData *data;
        memcpy(data,sendBytes,200);
        [socket writeData: data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    sendBuffer=nil;
}
```

Should I use NSMutablearrays instead?I admit, I am a beginner. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: -1 for not quoting the precise messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `*sendBuffer` refers to the first `Byte`in the `sendBuffer` array. Try this:

```
if (tcp) [tcp sendData: sendBuffer];
```

Oh, and you're missing a semicolon.